# How to quickly create large files in C in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, large-files, fallocate

Following this question:
[How to quickly create large files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776565/how-to-quickly-create-large-files-in-c)

I remember 4-5 years ago, I was able to use `fallocate` shell utility in Linux to create files without holes/gaps.

Disk filesystem was either ext3, ext4 or xfs.

At that time, `fallocate` shell utility created files of 8 GB in less one second. I do not remember if file was full of zeroes or random.

I try to replicate this nowadays, but it seems to create file with holes/gaps.

I am wondering how this was done in `C` language?

- Some kernel call that is Linux only?
- Some kernel call with error in specification that was later fixed?
- Some kernel call that is no longer available?

Comment: fallocate requires filesystem support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fallocate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) system call on Linux has an option to zero the space.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("testfile", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0755);
    off_t size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE, 0, size) == -1) {
        perror("fallocate");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Note that `FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE` may not be supported by all filesystems. `ext4` supports it.

Otherwise, you could write zeros yourself if you are looking for a more portable solution (which isn't that efficient, of course).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how this can be ported on MacOS / FreeBSD,without require root privileges?